# How do I check result of `npm run test` in bash conditional statement

Tags: bash

I have a deploy script I only want to run if my test is successful but believe there is an issue with my conditional statement `if [ "$VALID" ]`

```
#!/bin/bash

# install dependencies
echo 'INSTALLING YARN'
npm install yarn -g

echo "INSTALLING DEPENDENCIES"
yarn install

echo "TESTING"
VALID="$(npm test)"

if [ "$VALID" ]
    then    

    # ZIP up the code
    echo 'INSTALLING ZIP'
    apt-get update
    echo "y" | apt-get install zip

    echo 'ZIPPING'
    zip -r ./Lambda-Image-Compression.zip index.js node_modules

    # install aws cli so we can deploy code
    echo 'INSTALLING PIP'
    # echo "y" | apt-get install python-pip
    echo "y" | apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential 
    echo "y" | pip install --upgrade pip 
    # echo "y" | sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv 

    echo 'INSTALLING AWSCLI'
    pip install awscli

    # Copy config file to root so AWS config & credentials are set
    echo 'MAKING AWS CREDENTIALS'
    CREDENTIALS="[default]
    aws_access_key_id = $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    aws_secret_access_key = $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"

    touch .aws/credentials
    "$CREDENTIALS" > .aws/credentials

    echo "MOVING AWS CONFIG"
    cp -R .aws ~/.

    # Upload to AWS
    echo 'UPDATING LAMBDA FUNCTION'
    aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name resizeHandler \
    --zip-file fileb://Lambda-Image-Compression.zip \
    --region ap-southeast-2

fi
```

My test result if successful looks like:

```
> Lambda-Image-Compression@1.0.0 test 
> mocha

  myLambda
RUNNING OPTIMSATION
download
downloadImage: 69.381ms
End of step null
    ✓ Should move testImage.png from srcBucket to dstBucket and return true (286ms)


  1 passing (299ms)
```

Failure shows the following:

```
TEST RESULT:

> Lambda-Image-Compression@1.0.0 test
> mocha

  myLambda
RUNNING OPTIMSATION
download
    1) Should move testImage.png from srcBucket to dstBucket and return true


  0 passing (22ms)
  1 failing

  1) myLambda Should move testImage.png from srcBucket to dstBucket and return true:
     ReferenceError: s3 is not defined
      at download (index.js:32:4)
      at nextTask (node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5273:14)
      at Object.waterfall (node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5283:5)
      at exports.handler (index.js:24:8)
      at error (node_modules/lambda-tester/lib/runner.js:151:25)
      at Promise.resolve.then (node_modules/lambda-tester/lib/runner.js:138:24)
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: If `npm run test` does what it's supposed to by convention, it'll set its exit status based on test results. If it's doing that, then `if npm run test; then ...` will branch on test result. I'd **strongly** suggest validating whether it does or doesn't do that before trying anything fancier.

Comment: Try `npm run test; echo $?` both with and without failing tests. If it emits a 0 when all tests succeed and a nonzero value otherwise, then it's properly telling its parent process whether it had any failures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
VALID="$(npm test | grep -o 'failing')"
```

And then:

```
if [[ $VALID != "failing" ]] ...
```

Another way would be to pick up on "  0 passing":

```
VALID="$(npm test | grep -o '  0 passing')"
```

And for the conditional:

```
if [[ $VALID != "  0 passing" ]] ...
```

In either case if the word(s) "failing" or "  0 passing" are found in the returned string it would indicate the test was a failure. The key is to find something unique to the passing/failure output.

> <sub>**NOTE**: Study the output carefully; The "0 passing" string is not fool proof, since you technically could have 10 tests... grep would
>   see the "10 passing" and mistake it for a failure. Maybe you don't
>   have that many tests, but definitely be aware of it, or include the
>   exact number of spaces that are leading up to it.</sub>

Comment: Quick and easy solution. Thanks

Comment: what if test output includes pieces of code that contain word `'failing'`?

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is fairly old and has been answered already, I would like to share how I did it since the "correct" solutions seems a bit error-prone.

1. **Npm - Prebuild:**

Npm allows you to chain commands in the `package.json` file, allowing tests to run before your build:

```json
{
 "scripts": {
  "build": "<build>",
  "prebuild": "npm run test",
  "test": "<test>",
 }
}
```

so when your tests fail, the build command won't be executed. If your `build` command is called e.g. `deploy`, `prebuild` must be renamed to `predeploy`. (Check npm documentation [here](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/127671403050/testing-and-deploying-with-ordered-npm-run-scripts.html))

2. **Check if build was successful**

in your shell script now add the following logic:

1. delete build folder
2. build
3. check if build folder has been created

which could look something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
BUILD_DIR="./build"

rm -r $BUILD_DIR

npm run build

if [ -d "$BUILD_DIR" ]; then
    echo "Build was successful! Starting Deployment";
fi
```

Again, if your build folder is called differently, `BUILD_DIR` must be adjusted accordingly.