# grep result of npm test in bash conditional

Tags: bash, testing, npm, grep

I need to grep the result of an

> npm test

from my bash conditional.

So I can stop my CI/CD environment

there is a [suggestion to use grep like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620150/how-do-i-check-result-of-npm-run-test-in-bash-conditional-statement/44620190#44620190):

```
VALID="$(npm test | grep -o 'failing')"
```

but when I do that, just to try what actually is in the pipeline for "npm test"

```
VALID="$(npm test)"
```

What I see is:

```
echo "$VALID"

> MyApp@0.0.1 test /Users/NE/ts/project
> jest
```

SO, how will that work?
how can I really grep the result of the npm test?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Words like "failing" are meant for humans, not for computers. They should use the exit code instead:

```
if ! npm test
then
  # Tell the human about the failure, if the npm output wasn't enough
  echo >&2 "Testing failed"

  # Exit and tell computers about the failure (0 = success, 1+ = failure)
  exit 1
fi
```

And you can get the same effect more succinctly:

```
npm test || exit
```